# ORACLE | SUBSTR function not working

Tags: oracle, substr

I'm having an issue regarding SUBSTR function.

Imagine the table (**TABLE1**):

```
ABC_DEF   DESCRIPTION
--------  -------------
0999      TEST INFO
```

If I do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE 
(
     ABC_DEF = '0999'
)
```

I get this results:

```
ABC_DEF   DESCRIPTION
--------  -------------
0999      TEST INFO
```

However if I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE 
(
     ABC_DEF = SUBSTR('00000999', 5, 4)
)
```

I get 0 results. I don't understand the behavior at all. The attribute ABC_DEF is a char(8).

Comment: I'm using it in oracle sql developer and it works mate. I'm using it like that, because we are testing out an auto generated query to .c. EDIT: You're right. My fault on copying the query. It is normal parenthesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `CHAR(8)` column will right-pad the value with space (`CHR(32)`) characters until it has a length of 8.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3c3a6/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( ABC_DEF CHAR(8), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(20) );

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( '0999', 'TEST INFO' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ABC_DEF = '0999'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3c3a6/8/0)**:

```
|  ABC_DEF | DESCRIPTION |
|----------|-------------|
| 0999     |   TEST INFO |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ABC_DEF = SUBSTR('00000999', 5, 4)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3c3a6/8/1)**:

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ABC_DEF = RPAD( SUBSTR('00000999', 5, 4), 8, ' ' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3c3a6/8/2)**:

```
|  ABC_DEF | DESCRIPTION |
|----------|-------------|
| 0999     |   TEST INFO |
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That is indeed the solution. I'd say to Oracle, that this doesn't make sense. Using substr in that example should have been equal to make it equal to the value '0999'. However, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Use a `VARCHAR2(8)` column instead of a `CHAR(8)` column. The former is variable length whereas the latter is fixed width.

Comment: Perfect! That was it. I've tested based on your sqlfiddle and it works perfectly! Once again, thanks!